# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "employee" does not exist Position: 13

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to change the database from MySQL to PostgreSQL from the tutorial given on https://javainspires.blogspot.com/2020/07/spring-boot-2-spring-data-jdbc-jdbc.html. I am constantly having the error shown in the title.

**Employee.java**

```
package com. example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

public class Employee {

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public Employee() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Employee(String username, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**EmployeeController**

```
package com. example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @PostMapping(path = "addUser")
    public String addUser(Employee user) {
        
        String insert_query = "INSERT INTO employee (username,email,password) VALUES(?,?,?)"; 
        
        int rows = jdbcTemplate.update(insert_query,
                user.getUsername(), 
                user.getEmail(),
                user.getPassword());
        
        if(rows == 1) {
            return "success"; 
        } else {
            return "error"; 
        }
                
    
    }
    
}
```

**Html Files:
index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Java Inspires</title>
</head>
<body>

 <form th:action="@{/addUser}" th:object="${user}" method="post" >
 
  <p>User Name :<input type="text" name="username" /></p>
  <p>Email :<input type="email" name="email" /></p>
  <p>Password :<input type="password" name="password" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Sign Up" /></p>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    username varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDBC</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JDBC</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the schema.sql file and created it manually in PgAdmin4. The above code worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the schema name to your query.

```
INSERT INTO employee (username,email,password) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

from this to

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA_NAME.employee (username,email,password) VALUES(?,?,?)
```

If this does not work can you annotate the employee class with `@Entity and @Table(name = "TABLE_NAME"` may be the table name is user in your case.

And add @RequestBody annotation to the method parameter Employee `public String addUser(@RequestBody Employee user)`

Comment: Tried changing the the schema name to my query:

Comment: what happened after that?

Comment: Tried changing the the schema name to my query: didn't work

Annotating the user class with Entity, Table and Id and Column didn't work as well

Changed the user to employee to avoid any possible mishaps --didn't work
@raj240

Comment: Can you try adding currentSchema=SCHEMA_NAME to your spring.datasource.url  like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database?currentSchema=SCHEMA_NAME` with the Employee class being annotated as Entity and Table name also being specified.

Comment: The Employee class was annotated as: 
`@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
 
 @Id
 @Column(name="username")
 private String username;
 
 @Column(name ="email")
 private String email;
 
 @Column(name = "password")
 private String password;`

Comment: Try annotating @RequestBody for the employee request handler method in your controller.

Comment: Tried annotating the handler method, still gives the same error
`@PostMapping(path = "addUser")
 @ResponseBody
 public String addUser(Employee employee)`

Comment: Its @RequestBody for the Employee object. Not response body.

Comment: It tells me 
The annotation @RequestBody is disallowed for this location when I tried to add it

Comment: I directly created a table with columns in PgAdmin4 and the original code worked, the problem is probably in my table generation, which I assume needs some jpa configuration in application.properties. Thank you for taking time out of your day to help me.